# SwiftUI tvOS buttons look weird

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tvos

I'm trying to style a SwiftUI button the same for iOS and tvOS so it can be reused by both platforms... For iOS the styling went as expected without any issues but when running the same button on tvOS they look quite different than the iOS version:

iOS:

[image]

tvOS:

[image]

Why are there leading and trailing pieces on the tvOS version of the button?

```
...
var body: some View {
    Button(action: tapEvent) {
        HStack {
            if let image = icon, let uiimage = UIImage(named: image) {
                Image(uiImage: uiimage)
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .foregroundColor(iconColorForState(active: active, buttonMode: mode))
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
            }
            if let title = label {
                Text(title)
                    .lineLimit(1)
            }
        }
    }
    .foregroundColor(foregroundColorForState(active: active, buttonMode: mode))
    .padding()
    .disabled(disabled)
    .background(self.focused ? focussedBackgroundColorFor(active: active, mode: mode) : backgroundColorFor(active: active, mode: mode))
    .frame(height: heightForButtonSize(size: size ?? .Base))
    .cornerRadius(8)
    .modifier(FocusableModifier { focused in
        self.focused = focused
    })
}
```

Comment: Try to use `PlainButtonStyle`

Comment: This actually removed the left & right block, thanks

Comment: This issue is the same on macOS! not just tvOS, you can do what Asperi said or you work on Text and add on tab gesture to it, that would work also.